# sort phone contacts in descending and ascending order

Tags: android, sorting, contacts

I am loading the contacts of my phone in a list view and I am sorting them in ascending order.

Now I have 2 buttons: <kbd>Ascending</kbd> and <kbd>Descending</kbd>. How can I change the list view to show the contacts in ascending and descending orders depending on the button clicked?

Comment: you can use Collections.sort() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for ascending,

```
    ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        //get the data of each contact and store in list (here the item is Contact object)
        //for example
        Contact contact=new Contact();
        contact.setName("//get name of contact");
        contact.setPhonenumber("//get phonenum of contact");
        contactArrayList.add(contact);


    }
    phones.close();
    Collections.sort(contactArrayList, new Comparator<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Contact lhs, Contact rhs) {
            //get the item which is to be compared
            //here I have used name(String) of the contacts
            String lhsString = lhs.getName();
            String rhsString = rhs.getName();
            return lhsString.compareToIgnoreCase(rhsString);
        }
    });
```

for descending order,

```
return rhsString.compareToIgnoreCase(lhsString);
```

Comment: where should I place this?

Comment: after getting the list

Comment: @ladyBug please edit your post and you need to sort(use the code) after storing all data to the list

Comment: can you be more specific please because I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I have edited my answer. Here I have declared a class Contact and used arraylist<Contact> for example. You can do for any type of arraylist

Comment: Thanks It worked. now how am I going to change the list from ascending to descending and vice versa when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: Happy to help you ;)